# How to integrate $\int{x^a e^{-x} \, dx}$, if a is not an integer?

Tags: integration

$$\int{x^a e^{-x} \, dx}$$

If $a$ is an integer, I know that you can use integration by parts to obtain an answer in the form of a series expansion. I'm not sure how to solve it if $a$ isn't an integer however (besides numerical integration).

Edit: Sorry, this is a definite integral with positive bounds

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: take a look at the definition of $\Gamma$ function when the integration bounds are from $0$ to $\infty$ ...

Comment: Are you talking about the indefinite integral, or the integral over $[0, +\infty)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\Gamma(a+1)$
Note that it has the following properties that $\Gamma(a+1)=a\Gamma(a)$ and $\Gamma(1)=1$

Comment: I should have said that this is a definite integral with positive interval. Would the gamma function still work for this?

Comment: you will get incomplete Gamma functions

Comment: Thanks I used the lower incomplete gamma function to solve it